# ExcelWriter.Style CellLocked - why won't it work?

Tags: c#, styles, officewriter

I'm trying to create a simple example with #officewriter #excelwriter and having trouble using the styles.  Not sure why.

```
ExcelApplication XLAPP = new ExcelApplication();
Workbook WB = XLAPP.Create(); 
Worksheet WKST = WB.Worksheets[0];
DataSet ds = <...some valid dataset with 2 columns....>
DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
DataImportProperties props = WB.CreateDataImportProperties();
SoftArtisans.OfficeWriter.ExcelWriter.Style dataStyle = WB.CreateStyle();
props.UseColumnNames = true;
dataStyle.BackgroundColor = Color.SystemColor.Red;
dataStyle.CellLocked = true;                 
Area importArea = WKST.ImportData(dv, WKST.Cells[0, 0],props);
importArea.ApplyStyle(dataStyle);
XLAPP.Save(WB, Page.Response, "Output.xls", false);
```

Here's the problem:  the color style works in the output but the CellLocked style does not.  Why?

Thanks for any help.  Frustrated - I thought this was a simple example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExcelWriter is designed to mimic Excel, so usually the steps that you need to take in Excel to active certain properties are the same steps that you need to take in ExcelWriter.

In Excel, all the cells in a worksheet have the **locked** style property set, but that property will not take effect until the worksheet is protected. (Right click on a cell and go to *Format Cells > Protection* - the *Locked* property is checked, but the cells are not locked until you go to *Review > Protect Sheet*).

Similarly, in ExcelWriter, all the cells in [Worksheet.Cells](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Worksheet.Cells) have the [Style.CellLocked](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Style.CellLocked) set to **true** by default, but that property will not take effect until [Worksheet.Protect()](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Worksheet.Protect%28String%29) is called.  Once you protect the sheet, the cells should be locked.

```
ExcelApplication xlapp = new ExcelApplication();
Workbook wb = xlapp.Create(ExcelApplication.FileFormat.Xlsx);
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

//Currently, all the cells have default "locked" style set to true
//Protecting the worksheet will activate this property
ws.Protect("MyPassword");

xlapp.Save(wb, "ProtectedWorksheet.xlsx");
```

Since all the cells default to **Locked**, if you want to lock only an area of cells and not the entire worksheet, you will need to set Style.CellLocked to **false** on any cells that you want to leave unlocked. When the worksheet is protected, these cells will remain editable.

```
ExcelApplication xlapp = new ExcelApplication();
Workbook wb = xlapp.Open("MyWorkbook.xlsx");
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

//Create a style that will leave certain cells unlocked 
//when the worksheet is protected
Style unlockStyle = wb.CreateStyle();
unlockStyle.CellLocked = false;

//Select the area that will be left unprotected
//Apply the style to that area
Area unlockedArea = ws.PopulatedCells;
unlockedArea.ApplyStyle(unlockStyle);

//Protect the worksheet
ws.Protect("MyPassword");

xlapp.Save(wb, "MyNewWorkbook.xlsx");
```

For more about protecting worksheets, we have a guide in our documentation: [Protecting Your Worksheet](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Protecting+Your+Worksheet).

*Note: I work for SoftArtisans, makers of OfficeWriter.*

Comment: Hi - thanks for the advice.  I have used it now with success.  How do I lock specific or selected columns or rows?

Comment: Actually, better yet how do I lock specific or selected columns or rows dynamically based on the data present in the dataset?

Comment: I updated the answer so it includes a code snippet for how to lock only a specific area of cells. In the snippet, I use Worksheet.PopulatedCells (http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Worksheet.PopulatedCells) to return a rectangular area of the populated cells in the worksheet. If you wanted to unlock entire columns, you could use the Area from PopulatedCells, then check the Area.Firstcolumn, Area.ColumnCount and then iterate through each column with Worksheet.GetColumnProperties() and call ColumnProperties.ApplyStyle() instead.